# How to round corners of an image in AWS Serverless image handler using Sharp library

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sharp

I am working on AWS Serverless image handler. As per the document we need to append base64 encoded string to the base url. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/deployment.html

Here is the link to sharp library doc: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com

We can do this in cloudinary by passing r_200 as follows
https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_150,h_100,c_fill,r_200/Pi.png

Is there any way to achieve this using sharp???

Answer (score 0):

These are the Operations Sharp supports - [LINK](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-operation)

Rounding the corner is not one of them